# Characterizing elements in $X^{\ast}\hookrightarrow L^{\infty}(G)$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am in the following situation:

> Let $G$ be a locally compact group (possibly Hausdorff). Let $\Phi:L^{1}(G)\twoheadrightarrow X$, where $X$ is a Banach space. Then ${}^{t}\Phi:X^{\ast}\hookrightarrow L^{\infty}(G)$, where ${}^{t}\Phi(x^{\ast})(f)=x^{\ast}(\Phi(f))$ for all $x^{\ast}\in X^{\ast}$ and $f\in L^{1}(G)$. Given $f\in L^{\infty}(G)$, how do I check whether $f\in {}^{t}\Phi(X^{\ast})$?

Am I right in assuming that $f\in{}^{t}\Phi(X^{\ast})$ iff $\int_{G}f\psi\operatorname{d}m_{G}=0$ for all $\psi\in\operatorname{ker}\Phi$?.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Generally, you have $\ker T = {}^\perp\mathcal{R}({}^tT)$. Here, the closed range theorem gives you $\mathcal{R}({}^t\Phi) = (\ker \Phi)^\perp$.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Closed range theorem was the word...